# How can I multiply or swap the individual coordinates of a Vector?

Tags: python

I have two vectors that I would like to print to a file but before that I would like to multiply x and y in the first with -1 so instead of Vector((5, -10, 0)) it should be ((-5, 10, 0)) and in the second I would like to change order of y and z from Vector((0.0, 0.5, 1.0)) to Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.5)).

Any ideas?

Comment: its simple.(its mainly a python question)
1) `a = Vector((5, -10, 0))` 
2) `a.z, a.y = a.y, a.z`
3) `a = -a`
4) print to file

Answer (score 3):

First one is simple, multiply by (-1,-1,1):

```
a = Vector((5,-10,0))
print(a * Vector((-1,-1,1)))
# output: Vector((-5.0, 10.0, 0.0))
```

Second - rearrange it like this:

```
b =  Vector((0.0, 0.5, 1.0))
print(Vector((b.x, b.z, b.y)))
# output: Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get NameError: name 'Vector' is not defined, is there some library that I miss?

Comment: `from mathutils import Vector`

Comment: Thanks, you are the best.

Comment: You can also scale the vector with `a *= -1` or `a = a * - 1`. Please note in this case `0` can become `-0` which is weird and can lead to problems if testing for equality.

Comment: @Gorgious X and Y was asked to be inverted, not the Z